# Templated copy assignment operator

Tags: c++, templates

As per cppreference, a copy assignment operator should non templated :

> A copy assignment operator of class T is a **non-template** non-static member function with the name operator= that takes exactly one parameter of type T, T&, const T&, volatile T&, or const volatile T&"

But in this sample program, i wrote a templated assignment operator, there is no compilation issue and it infact is called(and not default implicitly generated).

```
template<typename T1>
class Sample
{
public:
        T1 a;
        Sample(T1 b)
        {
                a=b;
        }

        template<typename T2>
        void operator  = (T2& obj2)
        {
                cout<<"This wont be called";
                (*this).a=obj2.a;
        }

};


        Sample<int> obj1(2);
        Sample<int> obj2(3);

        obj2=obj1;
```

**Output:**

```
This wont be called
```

Am i misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`template<typename T2> void operator = (T2&)` is not the copy-assignment operator.

so the default one `void operator = (const Sample&)` is generated.

but your is a better match for:

```
Sample<int> obj1(2);
Sample<int> obj2(3);
obj2 = obj1;
```

But with

```
const Sample<int> obj1(2);
Sample<int> obj2(3);
obj2 = obj1;
```

You will have your expected result:

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/375f9dc805f5bf4c)

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename T2>
    void operator=(T2& obj2) { ... }
```

defines a `operator=` function but it is not the copy-assignment operator as per the standard. To qualify as a copy-assignment operator, it has to be:

```
void operator=(Samble& obj2) { ... }
```

or better

```
Sample& operator=(Sample const& obj2) { ... }
```

---

Given your code, you may use:

```
Sample<int> a;
Samble<double> b;
b = a;
```

If you had the real copy-assignment operator, that would fail to compile.

Comment: In other words you are saying that operator=() is called assignment operator when it takes a concrete type as an argument and its not assignment operator but rather =() if the argument is template type(e.g. T). If this is what you are saying then aren't we just playing with words, because i see the meaning doesn't change